# When does DOTween.To() happen in Unity's "Order of execution for event functions"

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I have read Unity's [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).
Now I want to use DOTween.
So I have a question. When does DOTween.To() happen in Unity's "Order of execution for event functions"?
Does it happens in "Update" or "yield return null" or other event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply look this up in the [source code](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/tree/develop/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween)

`DOTween` doesn't use `Coroutines` in the background but rather reproduces their behavior itself.

Basically it is happening in [`TweenManager.Update`](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/blob/a6f14b8445fa32a12d72cde42e1dd3db9dda9db3/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/Core/TweenManager.cs#L402) which is called by the [`DOTweenComponent`](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/blob/a6f14b8445fa32a12d72cde42e1dd3db9dda9db3/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/Core/DOTweenComponent.cs#L70) in multiple places (`Update`, `LateUpdate` and `FixedUpdate`)

So basically it depends which update type a certain [`Tweener`](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/blob/develop/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/Tweener.cs) uses which is what is returned by [`DOTween.To`](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/blob/a6f14b8445fa32a12d72cde42e1dd3db9dda9db3/_DOTween.Assembly/DOTween/DOTween.cs#L514)

Comment: May I ask you 2 more question? -- How can I run DOTween source code? How can I debug DOTween in Unity? 
I haved downloaded the source code, but I don't know how to run the project. It seems there is no DOTween source code in Unity, so how can I debug it.